# Heroku-postbuild error when deploying nodejs and angular to heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, production, build-error

I have a app that is currently deployed on heroku and working perfectly fine. I created a new heroku app and tried to run the same branch. I installed nodejs and all the configuration is the same but for some reason the build is failing at heroku-postbuild: "ng build --prod". It works fine on the previous instance I have on heroku but wont work on the new one. I don't know what i am missing as the information on the error is minimal. I am attaching my package.json as well as the error message I get. any help will be appreciated and let me know if you need me to upload anything else.

package.json

```
  {
  "name": "eserver",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.5",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "11.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.0.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.135",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.66",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.0.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/w3c-web-usb": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.4.3",
    "angular-cc-library": "^2.1.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "apexcharts": "^3.25.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "exec": "^0.2.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "got": "^11.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.2",
    "ldbutton": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.0.2",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdb-angular-ui-kit": "^1.0.0-alpha3",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.8",
    "ng-chartist": "^4.1.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng-thermal-print": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.8.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-chess-board": "^2.0.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "pusher": "^2.2.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "readable-stream": "^3.6.0",
    "remote-pay-cloud": "3.1.0",
    "remote-pay-cloud-api": "^4.0.3",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "resize-base64": "^1.0.12",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

log and Error I am getting when deploying on heroku:

```
Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.13
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.9.0
       
       Resolving node version 10.13...
       Downloading and installing node 10.13.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.9.0 (replacing 6.4.1)...
       npm 6.9.0 installed
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       
       > eserver@0.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_d00ecea7
       > npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript
       
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ng -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ngcc -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/main-ngcc.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ngc -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/src/bin/ngc.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ng-xi18n -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/src/bin/ng_xi18n.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/tsc -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/tsserver -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
       
       > @angular/cli@13.1.4 postinstall /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
       
       + @angular/cli@13.1.4
       + typescript@4.5.5
       + @angular/compiler-cli@13.1.3
       added 271 packages from 168 contributors in 10.621s
       audited 2004 packages in 17.813s
       found 45 vulnerabilities (2 low, 26 moderate, 17 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
       
-----> Build
       Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > eserver@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_d00ecea7
       > npm i && ng build --prod
       
       
       > eserver@0.0.0 preinstall /tmp/build_d00ecea7
       > npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript
       
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ng -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ngc -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/src/bin/ngc.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ng-xi18n -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/src/bin/ng_xi18n.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/ngcc -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/ngcc/main-ngcc.js
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/tsc -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
       /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/bin/tsserver -> /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
       
       > @angular/cli@13.1.4 postinstall /tmp/build_d00ecea7/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
       
       + @angular/compiler-cli@13.1.3
       + @angular/cli@13.1.4
       + typescript@4.5.5
       updated 3 packages in 3.453s
       audited 2004 packages in 11.332s
       found 45 vulnerabilities (2 low, 26 moderate, 17 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
    'node-sass' usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future major version. To opt-out of the deprecated behaviour and start using 'sass' uninstall 'node-sass'.
- Generating browser application bundles...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Error: compiler_1.getMissingNgModuleMetadataErrorData is not a function
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! eserver@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm i && ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the eserver@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.CSj5i/_logs/2022-01-26T03_37_12_096Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the version of @angular/compiler-cli and @angular/compiler versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check if HEROKU_API_KEY is correct and that heroku_app_name is unique. Also this line seems sketcy: `Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts Running heroku-postbuild`. Maybe refactor `heroku-postbuild` in `build` and run only build.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried both the build script alone and the heroku-postbuild by it's self but still no luck, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Also another thing I noticed is if I remove the heroku-postbuild then the build succeeds but ng build prod is never called so the frontend doesnt show

Comment: So what if you add --prod to build script? (I have edited my answer with and example)

Comment: Tried that it still doesn’t work